# Get Image from RSS Feed in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, rss

I am currently getting the title, date, and link for item in an RSS feed.  I'm wanting to add the image for each item to my tableview cell and I know how to do that.  The problem I'm having is figuring out how to get the url for the image.

The XML with the image URL looks like this:

```
<description>&lt;img src="http://images.cdn.bigcartel.com/bigcartel/product_images/128552379/max_h-300+max_w-300/LipsITUNES.jpg" title="The Lips- Album Numero Dos" align="left" style="margin:0 10px 10px 0;" /&gt;

Picking up where the previous album left off (self-titled, don't go looking for "Album Numero Uno") The Lips return with 12 new songs and their unique blend of indie garage rock. 

Includes the single "Useless" and "My Name Is Suicide."</description>
```

This is also there:

```
<media:thumbnail height="75" url="http://images.cdn.bigcartel.com/bigcartel/product_images/128552379/max_h-75+max_w-75/LipsITUNES.jpg" width="75"/>
      <media:description type="html">
```

Comment: ur present implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `didStartElement` delegate method.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

   if (nil != qualifiedName)
   {
        elementName = qualifiedName;
   }

   if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"media:thumbnail"] ) 
   {
        self.currentItem.mediaUrl = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"url"];
   } 
}
```

Please check this for more details [iPhone RSS Reader Application with source code](http://www.imthi.com/blog/programming/iphone-rss-reader-application-with-source-code.php)

Comment: pls how can i get this image `<itunes:image href="http://feeds.frogpants.com/morningstream_cover.jpg"/>` I am using this library https://github.com/gcharita/XMLMapper